# Group Sql query by month number and year number

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written a query which is bring following data:

[image]

I want to further group it by month and year to bring total quiz and total pass for each month in the result set, I am stuck and i need help with this,

thank you

Comment: Have you tried `group by`?

Comment: Specify the wanted result too.

Comment: If you have written a query, and you want to to amend it, you should provide said query in the question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Don't post pictures of data (unless you want a photograph of a query as an answer). Do include DDL, sample data, your code, expected results and an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns

```
select QuizMont, QuizYear, .. aggregate values here
  ...
group by QuizMont, QuizYear
```

Comment: Will this be a problem if the month and year mixed from last year and this year? like 5-2019 and 5-2020

Comment: With `group by` each unique combination will be a group on it's own. So 5-2019 will be a separate group to 5-2020. It's the combination that counts